# The data reader is incompatible. A member of the type does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, postman

I have the following `stored-procedure` in a `controller`:

```
var insert_query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Call_Info>("exec [dbo].[insert_call_info] @call_id, @user_id, @call_arrive, @call_end, @info", 
                    new SqlParameter("call_id", call_id),
                    new SqlParameter("user_id", u_id),
                    new SqlParameter("call_arrive", call_arrive),
                    new SqlParameter("call_end", call_end),
                    new SqlParameter("info", info)
                    ).ToList();
```

I'm trying to call it through `POSTMAN` and I get the following error:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EMSMVCModel.Call_Info'. A member of the type, 'call_id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.",
```

`Call_info.cs` file has the following code:

```
namespace EMSMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Call_Info
    {
        public int call_info_id { get; set; }
        public int call_id { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> call_arrive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> call_end { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual Call Call { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Call_info table is the following. `call_info_id` is an auto-increment field so I won't add a value through a stored procedure.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Call_Info]    Script Date: 25/5/2020 12:29:43 μ.μ. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Call_Info](
    [call_info_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [call_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [call_arrive] [datetime] NULL,
    [call_end] [datetime] NULL,
    [info] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [call_info_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Call_Info]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([call_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Call] ([call_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Call_Info]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([user_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
GO
```

I have the `stored-procedure`.

```
GET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_call_info]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @call_id int,
    @user_id nvarchar(128),
    @call_arrive datetime,
    @call_end datetime,
    @info nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Call_info (call_id, user_id, call_arrive, call_end, info) VALUES (@call_id, @user_id, @call_arrive, @call_end, @info);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS call_info_id;

SET FMTONLY ON
END
```

Comment: The code is invoking `SqlQuery<Call_Info>` which expects a collection of `Call_Info` entity instances to be returned. You could replace `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS call_info_id;` in your insert proc with something like `declare @call_info_id int=scope_identity(); select call_info_id, call_id, user_id, call_arrive, call_end, info from Call_info where call_info_id=@call_info_id;` so as to return the record that was just inserted.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You can add your comment as a response to accept it.